# Style disabled ASP.NET Linkbutton with background image

Tags: asp.net, css, linkbutton

I am using a simple ASP.NET linkbutton control.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonDelete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

I am styling this button with the following css definitions:

```
.linkButtonDelete:link
{
    background: transparent url(/../images/btnRegular.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
.linkButtonDelete:hover
{
background: transparent url(/../images/btnHighlight.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
```

And here is the problem: If I disable the linkbutton (LinkButtonDelete.Enabled = false;) and then hover over the linkbutton, the background image shows btnHighlight.png (instead of btnRegular.png). I tested this in IE9 and Chrome. Same effect.

Is there any chance I can apply a "disabled" style with CSS only (please no Javascript!)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm keeping my other answer because it would work as well, but if you want a purely CSS solution, look into Attribute Selectors which are supported starting with CSS 2.1. Assuming ASP.NET sets the disabled attribute, you could add something like so:

```
.linkButtonDelete[disabled="disabled"]:hover
{
background: something else;   
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Perfect! Saved my day, because my real scenario is a bit more complicated than the given sample. Modifying the css does the trick for all of my link buttons. Thanks so much, Doozer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's acting exactly as you tell it to. It's showing the hover. If you don't want it to show the hover, when you are disabling the button, it sounds like you need to set the Class to something else and create a new class that doesn't have the hover.

```
LinkButtonDelete.Enabled = false;
//then
LinkButtonDelete.Attributes["class"] = "linkButtonDeleteDisabled"; // give it a new class
```

or

```
 LinkButtonDelete.CssClass = "linkButtonDeleteDisabled";
```

Comment: Thanks Doozer,
I was just hoping I could fix this with css only. For instance I was hoping I could do something like 
.linkButtonDelte:hover[disabled]
But this does not seem to work. If there is no easy way, I guess I have to go with your suggestion.

Comment: @IngmarBode Gotcha. Tried another solution for you with purely CSS